# Beamer miniframes: side-by-side section names and navigation dots

Tags: beamer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm using the beamer `miniframes` outer theme (with subsection=false).  Currently the navigation shows navigation dots below each section name.  I would prefer it if the dots came to the *right* the section name.  Is this possible?

Right now it looks like:

```
Sec 1           Sec 2
o o o o         o o o o
```

But I want it to look like:

```
Sec 1 o o o o               Sec 2 o o o o
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}  
\begin{document}  
\section{Sec 1}  
\subsection{}  
\begin{frame}[t]  
  hi  
\end{frame}  
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Good point (edited!)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be obtained by patching the internal `beamer` commands responsible for creating the mini frame navigation:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}  
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by -.05cm}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@vboxoffset\advance\beamer@tempdim by\beamer@boxsize\advance\beamer@tempdim by 1.2\pgflinewidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\slideentry}{\kern\beamer@tempdim}{\advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt\advance\beamer@tempdim by\wd\beamer@sectionbox\kern\beamer@tempdim}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Sec 1}
\subsection{}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Sec 2}
\subsection{}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

This hack moves the mini frames one line up<sup>*</sup> and (*length of the section title* + 2pt) units to the right, to end up in the desired position:

[image: mini frame navigation for "Sec 1", with mini frames to the right of the section name]

I have also added the `compress` option to the minimal working example, as if you have multiple subsections in your presentation, it may look strange if each subsection starts in a new line.

<sup>*</sup>To be more precise, it's one line plus `1.2\pgflinewidth`: The default circular mini frames descend exactly the amount of `\pfglinewidth` below the baseline, so I raised them to be a tiny amount above the baseline. You may have to play around with this value a little, especially if you use another mini frame style (`box`, `tick`) than the default circle.

Comment: wow, I learned a lot from this answer!